# Is puts or putchar better for printing just a newline?

Tags: c, newline, stdio

Which is better (in both performance and best practice) for printing *only* a newline:

`putchar('\n')` or `puts("")`

From what I understand, `putchar` outputs a single character and `puts` outputs a string of characters. [Forget about `printf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23749826/3893016).

I'm inclined to use `puts` because it's shorter, but doing `("")` just *feels* wrong.

Which is faster and better?

Comment: so... `fputc` shouldn't be in that list of options?, or just `putc`? May as well include them all (`putchar` equivalent to `putc(ch,stdout)`)

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer `putchar('\n')` but I don't have a good rational for it. It's just that I dislike `puts` because of its inconsistent behavior of adding a newline to the end while `fputs` does not.

Comment: You're worried about the *performance* of a buffered console that is going to be read by humans? If I told you that one of them was 8 microseconds faster than the other, would that be a reason to go for the one that serves up the newline to your waiting eyes that much faster?

Comment: Profile. But I strongly suspect that a macro whose sole purpose is to write a single character will do better (if only trivially) than a more general purpose function. Of course, if you were just using `puts` earlier, caching comes into play; hot code is likely faster than cold code even if the hot code has to execute a couple more instructions.

Comment: @EricLippert Not worried about it, curious about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any speed difference between them is going to be insignificant, but `putchar` is probably faster because it takes a single char argument.

Far more importantly, `putchar('\n')` is *saying what you mean*, while `puts("")` isn't.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, one requires a pointer, and an extra byte and the other doesn't.  As well, one could require more instructions and potentially blow some `i-cache`, which could be bad.  In practice the difference between the two is almost certainly negligible though.

However, I'd still personally use `putc` or `putchar` just because the code is easier for anyone else to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

A good compiler will emit the same optimized code for the below, so it is not a performance issue.

```
putchar('\n');
puts("");
```

Use the one that better conveys code's intent.  This often depends on what else is being printed.

```
// Example 1
putchar('(');
putchar(ch);
putchar(')');

putchar('\n');  // Better choice
// puts("");


// Example 2
puts(name);
puts(rank);
puts(serial_number);

// putchar('\n');  
puts(""); // Better choice
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though puts() allows you to output a string, you are outputting a string that has only a single character (the newline), so the result, and the performance, should be the same as using putchar().