# Printing a character multiple times in a for loop

Tags: c, printf

I want to use printf and for loop to print a character multiple times per line depending on the input; i.e. if the input is 3 i want to print:

```
a
aa
aaa
```

this is the loop, which doesn't work at all.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("a", i);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I just don't understand how to print it multiple times on a single line.

Comment: What do you expect `printf("a", i);` to do *and why*?

Comment: You finish the line for every character. \n is synonymous with end of line.

Comment: You will have to have another loop in that loop (`for n = 0; n<i+1; n++` ...) or use a function to repeat a chracter

Comment: Also, do you by chance come from a Python environment?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int i, j; 
 int n = 3;
 for (i=0; i < n; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++){
      printf("a");
      
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: well in my mind assuming n is 3 in the loop i will be 0, 1 and 2. when i is 0 i want to print a, when i is 1 i want to print aa and when i is 2 i want to print aaa and so on n times. and no i don't come from anywhere i assume. i just started learning a couple days ago and this was an exercise.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ow..

Comment: @Lupe :P :P :P :P

Comment: The easiest/clearest thing to do is change the first `printf` to a function call `printCharacters(char,int)` or something, and implement it `void printCharacters(char printedChar, int noOfPrints){ for( int i = 0; i < noOfPrints' ++i ) printf("%c", printedChar); }` NOTE: call the function to take a char i.e. `printCharacters('a',i+1);`

Comment: @George has a very strange understanding of "easiest/clearest thing to do", considering that exact functionality already exists in `printf` (see my answer)

Comment: @abelenky alright then, the answer is the "easiest"(shortest really) thing to do, but the clearest? I wonder how many people know of that functionality and if it was an intended solution to the op's exercise(which would normally be fine it wasn't only it's probable the exercise was to get the op to use a nested loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two nested `for` loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
       printf("a");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

As suggested in one of the comments in this answer and as per the discussion in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749797/putchar-vs-printf-is-there-a-difference), `putchar` is faster than `printf` if you are printing only one character. So if you are ok with using `putchar` instead of `printf`, try the following code instead:

```
char ch = 'a', newLine = '\n';
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
       putchar(ch);
    }
    putchar(newLine);
}
```

Comment: Even better, use putchar instead of printf.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the OP has stated that he wants to use `for` and `printf` (only).

Comment: That could be because OP is unaware that there is a better alternative. To say nothing of future readers of this question who might also appreciate the advice.

Comment: Cool. Updated the answer to include the `putchar` way too. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine, but a small addition. If i want to do the opposite as in have the max number of characters on top minimum on the bottom, what do i need to change in the loop? I tried to make j my max possible input which was 20, and then made it j-- instead of j++ but that seemed to create an infinite loop which crashed the program. Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: OK nevermind i figured it out. I used   `for (int k=n-1; k>=i; k--)` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you ***need*** to use a for-loop, I think this would be better for many cases:

```
printf("%.*s\n", 5, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
```

Which will print the first 5 letters of the string (which happens to be more than enough `a`'s)

Put into a complete program:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%.*s\n", i+1, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: I learned something! I am going to read an implementation or two to see its viability with longer strings but very cool.